# media query does not work correctly for mobile device - phone

Tags: android, css, media-queries

I've looked at similar questions on here and tried what they've shown, where people have resolved issues, but no luck for me.

I've got a basic bootstrap 4.4.1 CSS file hooked in and then my own custom CSS file as well.
At the bottom of it, I plug in the media queries:

```
@media screen and (min-width:176px) and (max-width: 459px) {
divboxshadow_rt {
    width: 320%; 
    float:left;
    background-color: #FFFCCC;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
 }
 .col col-md-8 px-md-6 { 
 width:80%; float:left
 }
}
@media (min-width:460px) and (max-width: 767px) {
 
.col-sm-3.col-xs-12{ width:50%; float:left}
.col-sm-4.col-xs-12{ width:50%; float:left}
.col-sm-6.col-xs-12{ width:50%; float:left}

}
```

This actually works in the dev console looking at it in one of my browsers in responsive mode, particularly one of the iPhone flavors. I have no intention of using this paltry bkg color but it does show as I alter it.
I've tried my site in both the stock browser and Chrome. I've got Android, Galaxy Samsung 9.

Is there some code override I need to use to get this to work? Or does something here look incorrect, despite the fact it's now looking correct in two dev consoles (Chrome and Avast)?

I need the col widths or the body width actually, to be a little wider in phone mode. The div box is getting scrunched up wrongly.

I welcome any feedback you folks will give me. I added another class and revised my question below, slightly. I cannot get that one class to override its original. Am I doing that incorrectly? i.e. override divboxshadow_rt with the media query version? Actually very close now.
I have

```
   <div class="col col-3 .px-md-6 divboxshadow_rt " >
```

I am attempting/needing to override the col col-3 with col col-md-8 as plugged into the media query for small devices above. Would it not override that? the col col-3 stays in tact, and isn't affected in my responsive testing. Perhaps I'm not approaching it correctly, but I thought the media query above would override the setting. No? Again, any feedback is welcomed.

Comment: I think **screen size** isn't compatible with source code **width** and **height** size

Answer (score 0):

// No media query necessary for xs breakpoint as it's effectively `@media (min-width: 0) { ... }`

You only need to write **col-12** instead col-xs-12

```
@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) { ... }
@include media-breakpoint-up(md) { ... }
@include media-breakpoint-up(lg) { ... }
@include media-breakpoint-up(xl) { ... }
```

you only override the width and float styles in your custom css

Comment: OK, thank you. in deference to my original question above, I am finding that I can only override the current class attached to the div with the body attributes. But let's say I have the class "divboxshadow_rt" on the div - wouldn't I add it to the media query above for the phone setting, and it shoud override the original? I'll edit that one to show the example.

Comment: Hi Nikhil, it did not exactly do it. What I ended up doing to get it to work correctly was prebuild the HTML class css reference. It may indeed read the media query but I had to hard code each of those class names in the HTML tag. Thank you for the tip, though, as it may also contributed to the fix in a small way!